# How often do Olympic divers score a zero?

Tags: olympics, diving

I've been amazed at the headlines about so many Olympic divers scoring zeros during competition. Is this common in Olympic diving? If so, is there an easy explanation? It just seems odd to me that divers could misjudge their dives so badly as to do so many bellyflops. If gymnasts did this, they would be leaving on stretchers a LOT!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is never common in a diving competition which is usually held in indoor swimming pools. The biggest cause of those belly flops and misjudgement of dives was a very strong wind.

The [diving pool at the London Olympics](http://www.londonaquaticscentre.org/) was indoor and there was no wind. However, as you can see in the below image, the diving pool at Rio is outdoor

[image]

The diving pool has been a big embarrassment for Rio organizers and they should be blamed for not having anticipated the effect of strong gush of wind on divers when it could be powerful enough to knock down aerial camera and cables injuring seven people.

[Rio Olympics: Seven injured when aerial camera, cables fall in Olympic Park](http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/olympics/rio-2016/2016/08/15/camera-fall-olympic-park-rio/88765972/)

[Diving: Winds help knock Chinese world champion out in preliminaries](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-olympics-rio-diving-m-3mspringboard-idUSKCN10Q27T)

> "It was the wind that really affected the start of my dive. We didn't
>   train in these kinds of very windy conditions before at all,"

I am confident that future Olympic organizers will take the wind factor more seriously than Rio organizers did. It's another shame for Rio.

Comment: Is this the same pool that had to be completely drained and cleaned because it was infested with algae a couple of days ago?